# How can I create drawable file compatible with all devices on both orientations in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-compatibility, android-resolution

I have created a rectangle structure with a tooltip arrow using a layer list. And showing this as a popup window. But that pop-up left and right ends are cutting for Large tablets on portrait mode.

Structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:paddingStart="-10dp">
     <item android:top="20dp" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners  android:radius="8dp"/>
                <padding android:top="20dp" android:right="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="206dp" android:height="100dp" />
                <solid android:color="#FFF" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#d9d9d9" />
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    
        <item
    
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:end="14dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:top="-10dp">
    
            <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
                >
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#d9d9d9" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#d9d9d9" />
    
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    
        <item
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:end="14dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:top="-7dp">    //here, -12 + 3 = -9
    
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45">
    
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
    
                    <solid
                        android:color="@color/white_color" />    
      </shape>
    
            </rotate>
    
        </item>
    
    </layer-list>
```

popup.xml be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_recta">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
     <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="Log out"
                    android:textColor="#515151"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_help"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="Help"
                    android:textColor="#515151"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_report"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Report an issue"
                    android:textColor="#515151"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_history"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:background="#f6f6f6"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/history_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="Unsubmitted Inspections"
                    android:textColor="#515151"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_icons_badges_gr_count_ylw" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageViewText"
                        android:layout_width="12dp"
                        android:layout_height="12dp"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myImageView"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/myImageView"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/myImageView"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myImageView"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
    
                </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And the popup opened using below code :

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
   PopupWindow mypopupWindow = new PopupWindow(view,850, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                   mypopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
                    mypopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v,0,10);
                    mypopupWindow.setElevation(20);
```

How can I make it compatible with all devices on both orientations?

Answer (score 0):

You have set custom width to the layout. That's why it's getting cut in some devices. Try applying proper width according to device size.